# Getting the month from a graph in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

I have a graph in a report that is showing the number of tickets open for this year plus the past 3 years by month.  I want to click on a bar in a given month, like March, for one of the years to bring up a details screen.  It works fine for January but it is not passing the right month for any other month.  I am assuming that it will work fine for February next month but probably won't work for January any more.  How can I pass it the month base on which month I click on the graph?

Thanks,
Donald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out by using a different query.